# Integrate Vidstack within an Ionic framework built using Angular library

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, html5-video, progressive-web-apps, plyr.js

I'm trying to build an app using the Ionic framework built using Angular library. On the app I want to use the Vidstack library to display video files, but the Vidstack docs has no support for Angular, only HTML and React.

https://www.vidstack.io/docs/player/getting-started/installation

I would appreciate some help so I could integrate Vidstack within an Ionic framework built using Angular library.

Thanks!